# React-Redux , issues reading an object fetched through redux thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a redux action / reducer that looks like the following.
Action:

```
export function loadServerInfo() {
    return (dispatch) => axios.get(`${config.SERVER}/redis/server/info`).then(res => {
        if (res.status == 200) {
            dispatch(fetchServerInfo(res.data))
        }
    }).catch(err => {

    })
}

export function fetchServerInfo(payload) {
    return {
        type: GET_SERVER_INFO,
        payload
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
const defaultState = {
    decodedRedisKey: {},
    keyDecoded: false,
    serverInfo: {}
}

const redisReducer = (state = defaultState, action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_REDIS_KEY_INFO: {
            return {
                ...state,
                decodedRedisKey: action.payload
            }
        }
        case REDIS_KEY_DECODED: {
            return {
                ...state,
                keyDecoded: action.payload
            }
        }
        case GET_SERVER_INFO: {
            console.log(action.payload) //this is fired and logs the proper data, which is an object
            return {
                ...state,
                serverInfo: action.payload
            }
        }
        default:
            return {
                ...state
            };
    }
}

export default redisReducer;
```

Then I have a component connected and mapped to redux. Those are the connection parameters

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => state;

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        loadServerInfo: async () => {
            dispatch(loadServerInfo());
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UsersContainer);
```

And after that, I try to call the fetch, and get the data.
Problem is that the format of the object is as follows:

```
serverInfo: {
  Server : {
  uptime_in_days: "100",
  version: "1.0.0"
 }
}
```

My prop is firing on useEffect

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
        getUsersToken();
        props.loadServerInfo();

        console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_ENV)
    }, []);
```

If i put it in a useEffect, first it logs undefined and afterward it loads

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("server info")
    console.log(props.redisReducer.serverInfo)
    console.log(props.redisReducer.serverInfo.Server)
    // console.log(props.redisReducer.serverInfo.Server.uptime_in_days) , if i uncomment this it crashes
}, [props.redisReducer.serverInfo])
```

So im having issues rendering the uptime_in_days value

I have tried doing this

```
{props.redisReducer.serverInfo != undefined && !displayServerInfo != undefined ?
                        <div className="basic-server-info-data">
                            <p><img src={redisLogo} /></p>
                            {/* <p>Connected Clients: <i>{serverInfo.Clients.connected_clients} </i></p> */}
                            {/* <p>Memory usage:  <Progress type="circle" percent={memoryUsageStats} width={50} /> </p> */}
                            <p>Tokens (displayed): <i>{usersToken.length}</i></p>
                            <p>Uptime: <i>{props.redisReducer.serverInfo.Server.uptime_in_days} days</i></p> 
                        </div>
                        :
                        null
                    }
```

It keeps crashing in the Uptime line, even tho im doing a check if its not undefined

> Cannot read property 'uptime_in_days' of undefined

I tried changing the render condition to

```
props.redisReducer.serverInfo != undefined && !displayServerInfo != undefined &&  props.redisReducer.serverInfo.Server.uptime_in_days != undefined
```

But nothing changes.

How can I render that value?

EDIT: I have noticed this error

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

in my useEffect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is that all your null checks start with the always defined state, `props.redisReducer.serverInfo`

```
const defaultState = {
  decodedRedisKey: {},
  keyDecoded: false,
  serverInfo: {} // <-- defined!
}
```

`state.serverInfo` is always a defined object, so `console.log(props.redisReducer.serverInfo)` and `console.log(props.redisReducer.serverInfo.Server)` will always log, and the condition `props.redisReducer.serverInfo != undefined` will always be true.

You neglect to do a null check on `props.redisReducer.serverInfo.Server` before accessing the uptime value

```
props.redisReducer.serverInfo.Server.uptime_in_days
```

I'm guessing your UI is blowing up on the initial render before state is populated.

## Solutions

Use Optional Chaining to handle the null check on `Server` being possibly undefined still.

```
props.redisReducer.serverInfo.Server?.uptime_in_days
```

Use conventional null checks

```
props.redisReducer.serverInfo.Server && 
props.redisReducer.serverInfo.Server.uptime_in_days
```